# How to add themeroller custom theme to my website?

Tags: jquery-mobile, themeroller

I have created a custom theme using Jquerymobile.com themeroller.
A mobile website which i have created using default theme values like .js and .css folders.
Now i want to change that theme of my website to my new custom theme,created using themeroller.
How to include those files to my coding?

Answer (score 1):

When you download the themerolloer that you create, there is a sample index.html file that uses the theme that is enclosed.  Look at that to see what files need to be included in your page, but more importantly, look at that code to see what CSS classes are being used - no point in including them in your page if you aren't using using the Themeroller classes

You can see all the steps, and a full tutorial on the [Getting Started](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/) page

Comment: Why hasn't this been accepted as answer? Anyways, I found your reply because I had the same question. Subsequently I found that the "Getting Started" link was outdated. The current one is: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/